# Creating shortcode functionality like Wordpress in php or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to create WordPress like shortcode with php or Laravel.

Like if i use this one [table=table_name],it should fetch all records from table_name,and then display it on the page or post on the frontend but not at the backend as WordPress does.

Any sample code or example would be great to get started.

Comment: Why you want shortcode you can use any  WYSIWYG editor

Comment: As i need to provide the option to display any table's data on any page or post,which is not possible with WYSIWYG @AjayDeepakKumar

Comment: you can try `tinymce` or `Ckeditor` or same

Comment: Perhaps you are not getting my point,how can i display table A record in a page or post,Or can add Table B,C records as well with WYSIWYG @AjayDeepakKumar

Comment: but this will make you app vulnerable.

Comment: Yes agreed,but it is the requirement that user can display specified table's data in any page or post.

Answer (score 2):

Google "Laravel Shortcode" and you'll have some ideas. There's a component that looks really good, but isn't updated for 3 years:

https://github.com/patrickbrouwers/Laravel-Shortcodes

That would be a good start point. I even encourage you to fork the component, update it to Laravel 5 and create a pull request, instead of create a hole new script.

As of the table exemple, you would extend like this:

```
Shortcode::register('table', function($shortcode, $content, $compiler, $name) {
    $items = DB::table($shortcode->table)->get();
    $table = '<table class="table-'. $shortcode->table. '">';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // @todo prepare all inner table here
        $table .= '<tr><td>...</td></tr>';
    }
    $table = '</table>';
});
```

And use it as `Shortcode::compile('<h1>Users:</h1> [table table="users"]');`